# Detect if Excel 2013 is installed

Tags: registry, excel-2013

Excel 2010 can be detected by checking the presence of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\InstallRoot in the registry.

It would seem for Excel 2013 that HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\InstallRoot doesn't work.

How can you detect if Excel 2013 is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach outlined here: [Where is a reliable registry key to find install location of Excel 2007?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244517/where-is-a-reliable-registry-key-to-find-install-location-of-excel-2007) still works.

Office 2013 allows you to start using applications in the office suite while the rest of Office installs. The same key works ONLY once Office 2013 is completely installed.